# maskedinput Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function

Tags: javascript, symfony, maskedinput

Good afternoon
On my  there is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/reflorestasite/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/reflorestasite/js/validacoes.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
```

And on "validacoes.js" file there is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
  $('.cpf').blur(function () {
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var val=$(this).val();
    var pattern = new RegExp(/[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2}/);

    if(val.match(pattern) == null){
      $("#"+id+"_error").html("Digite um CPF válido");
    }
  });
});
```

I've already verifed at console and all javascript files are there. However i'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function"

Does anyone has a clue why symfony is not recognizing the maskedinput plugin?

Thankyou very much.

Comment: Are you sure the jquery.maskedinput.min.js is being loaded in your page? [Sample fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3g8gdysv/) shows your code to be working outside of symfony2 framework so you have a missing file or bad path or filename

Comment: yes I'm sure. I've looked into the source-code through google chrome and I was able to open the masked input file by clicking on it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change this line from

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function($){
```

Comment: i had the same error and your solution worked, can you please explain what is the difference between two?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion however this did not resolve my issue of ".mask is not a function"

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to see your answer. I marked as correct because it solved the problem to cagdasumay and I pretty sure it would solve my problem as well If I had seen it that time.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're using `jQuery.noConflict()`, be sure to use this instead: `$(document).ready(function(jQuery){`

Comment: ?! can anybody explain why does this work now? I used $(function(){} before.

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error too, but in my case I forgot to import maskedinput.min.js

```
<script src="/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I was searching Google for a solution haha.

Comment: Such a simple thing and it was what I was missing too.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, I had to remove duplicate script connections

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
```